# Change vibration pattern

Tags: vibration, android-10

So there is this thing that has annoyed me since my Samsung Galaxy S8. The default vibration pattern for notifications (when on vibrate mode) seems to be two short vibrations.

This is driving me nuts as I always have my smartphone on vibrate but I want it to only vibrate once, one short "bing" kind of vibration.

I tried several apps which allow you to control the vibration pattern, but they all seem to work only if not in vibrate mode or for older types of OS (< 8). Mind you that this is pretty much only about WhatsApp, as I don't receive many messages via SMS or anything else. Changing the pattern in WhatsApp does nothing (it keeps vibrating literally exactly the same), external Apps do something sometimes (sometimes 3 vibrations, sometimes 1, most often still 2, and nothing is really reproducible). Finally, Android itself does not really give you any control over vibrations unless I miss something.

I even had a look at the source code which (if I understand correctly) hardcodes the vibration pattern fallback for vibrate mode and does not allow any changes.

I know that it sounds really stupid but this is such a big grind for me, that I even consider switching the OS, as it drives me insane. So if anybody has any help it would be much appreciated.

If relevant, the device is an Essential Phone running Android 10. There is no "Sounds and Vibrations" setting, there is only a "Sound" setting which allows me to change the call and notification sounds but not the patterns.

Comment: Added the device model and Android version because each manufacturer can customize their own Android, as shown on the answer for Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings --> Sounds and Vibrations. There is an option "Vibration Pattern". Change that to "Basic Call".

As pointed out in a comment to this answer, probably this setting is available only in Samsung phones. I haven't checked devices from other manufacturers.

Comment: I would, but there is no "Sounds and Vibrations" setting, there is only a "Sound" setting which allows me to change the call and notification sounds but not the patterns. (This is on Essential Phone with Android 10)